# Best way to upload multiple .NET Core packages with dependencies to each other to NuGet?

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core, package, asp.net-core-mvc

I have .NET Core C# class library projects that I want to upload to NuGet [available here](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc/tree/master/src).

Some of these packages depend on others from the solution. For example MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc depends on MyTested.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.

Since there is slight delay of indexing when uploading a package to NuGet how can I overcome the following problem:

1. I start uploading packages (CI or manual)
2. 3 of 9 (or more) packages are already uploaded but the rest are still missing
3. While I upload them, someone tries to download a package but its dependencies are not indexed yet
4. He receives an error that a package is missing

What are my best options here?

Should I upload the packages starting from the lowest dependent package and finishing with the most dependent one? Since the number of packages may increase in the future, this may become quite tedious work to manage.

Should I unlist all packages untill they are all uploaded and then list them at once?

Anything else as solution? I wonder how Microsoft is doing with .NET Core and ASP.NET Core where they have hundreds of packages depending on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (remembering from a [community standup](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_7v3Hra_NAhWRHsAKHfvHAPgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flive.asp.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNHDqrNXBvAg7qTLLciM_rMswvMDeg&sig2=HYPRPB5eVeGNtJCHT-GiXw&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg)), that the team uploads all the packages in an un-listed state, then flicks the switch to have them listed/indexed.